# How to replace %E2%80%8E with slash (/) using .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

Following image is my hosting directory, .htaccess locations and more explanation. Please kindly have a look.

Image is here >>> [my hosting and sites directories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRcrL.png)

**Problem:** Somebody link to my blog and he accidently linked to `www.abc.com/blog%E2%80%8E` instead of `www.abc.com/blog/`. I beleive `%E2%80%8E` is the slash `/`.

[**Edit:**] I have contacted him to link to correct url but got no reply from him.

**Question:** How to change `%E2%80%8E` to slash `/` using `.htaccess`?

**Informations:**

1. `abc.com` has html files & one `.htaccess` file
2. `abc.com/blog/` has running wordpress and another one `.htaccess` file
3. Normally working 301 redirect code in `abc.com/blog/` is `Redirect
   301 /abc.com/blog/asdf /blog/` (but that format doesn't work for
   `%E2%80%8E`)

Please let me know if you need more information. Thanks in advance!

Comment: That's easy. Contact whoever runs the other site and inform them of the error. They will fix the URL without you having to make any changes.

Comment: I'm sorry that I forgot to mention that I have contacted him but got no reply. I will include this in question. Thanks for providing your thought. :)

Answer (score 2):

That other dude got your links totally wrong cause `%E2%80%8E` is in fact the URL encoding of the UTF-8 encoded unicode codepoint U+200E (LEFT-TO-RIGHT MARK). To cath their link juice anyway, the following might work (note the `B` flag):

```
RewriteRule  ^(.+)%E2%80%8E(.*)$  $1/$2 [B]
```

Comment: Hi Hagen,

It work on non-www version but after seeing 404 page. It doesn't work with www version. Any idea please?